# How do I find the index of an item in a PriorityQueue? (Java)

Tags: java, priority-queue

I was wondering if it was possible for me to find the index of a value in a PriorityQueue . Just to see what number it is "in line". Does anyone know?

Answer (score 5):

There is an index priority queue written by Princeton.

algs4.cs.princeton.edu/24pq/IndexMinPQ.java.html

The key idea is to build two index maps between the item and its position in priority queue.

When you are updating the priority queue, you also need to update those two index maps.

Hope this solves your problem :-)

Comment: the link is now at https://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/24pq/IndexMinPQ.java.html

Answer (score 4):

PriorityQueue doesn't support indexing. You can yourself associate an integer index to each item.

Comment: Yes, have a look at code : http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/PriorityQueue.java#PriorityQueue

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the first line in the documentation you'll see:

```
An unbounded priority queue based on a priority heap.
```

You can't use a priority heap to find the index of an element effectively. It only knows the first one and when you pop it out it then recalculates the new first one etc.

Answer (score 0):

I had a `PriorityQueue<Integer[]> queue` where the index was the first element of the array. So I did this method, where it finds the element then actually removes it from the queue.

Since this method was used only with existent indexes, I added the `orElseThrow` to deal with empty `Optional`'s

```
static Integer[] getByIndex(Integer i, PriorityQueue<Integer[]> queue) {
  Integer[] node = queue.stream().filter(n -> n[0].equals(i)).findAny().orElseThrow(
      () -> new NullPointerException("node " + i + " not found on queue")
  );
  queue.remove(node);
  return node;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a quick fix;
the better approach would be the one submitted by Ming Li.

This issue can be solved using the `poll()` and `peek()` methods:
The `poll()` method retrieves the topmost element and removes it.

Let's say you want to check the kth element from a `PriorityQueue` named `pq`:

```
for(int i=0; i<k-1; i++){
        pq.poll();
    }
```

Next, we use the `peek()` method to see the topmost element of the `PriorityQueue`:

```
pq.peek();
```

this returns the topmost element of the `PriorityQueue`, which in this case would be the one at kth position.